# Firebase Update Multiple Items

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I update multiple items on firebase with just one request?

I can not let my system wait to complete multiple requests, so I need to update them with just one.

---

Current Firebase Data:

[image]

---

PHP Code:

```
$data = [
    'mydata-1' => [
        'position' => 1,
    ],
    'mydata-2' => [
        'position' => 2,
    ],
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->put(FIREBASE_ENDPOINT . '/data', [
    'json' => $data,
]);
```

---

Expected Firebase Data:

[image]

---

Problem:

The request subscribe all my data and I lose the `title` field.
I also tried `PATCH` request, but I got the same response.

[image]

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Aside from that: https://disqus.com/home/discussion/firebase/introducing_multi_location_updates_and_more_firebase_38/#comment-2276358402

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. Please consider to send it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Frank van Puffelen comment:

```
$data = [
    'mydata-1/position' => 1,
    'mydata-2/position' => 2,
];

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->patch(FIREBASE_ENDPOINT . '/data', [
    'json' => $data,
]);
```

---

Documentation:
https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html